# do I need to do something if I want to use some api?

Tags: api, eventbrite

I wanted to use **Eventbrite** API which I saw from http://eventbrite.github.com/#examples 
and

**Search event list (jsFiddle)**

In jsfiddle.net/zTyZz/72/ I can use **eventbrite** but any other script tester didn't accept eventbrite.

It said **"ReferenceError: Eventbrite is not defined"**

Then.. Do I need to import the Eventbrite or something else? How?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on 'Manage Resources' in the left hand panel of jsFiddle.

You'll need to source the client library in order to reference it: 
https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/Eventbrite.jquery.js/blob/master/example.html#L8

Comment: Oh I saw it, thanks. (<script type="text/javascript" src="Eventbrite.jquery.js"></script>)
hmm.. it means do I need to get "Eventbrite.jquery.js" first?